# Get page name when user switches to some other page in a report

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have a report that contains more than 1 pages.
Now I want to add a functionality in my report such that whenever I switch to some other page then I get to know the page name so that I can assign my page name value to some global variable

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `event handler` which will get called when the Report `page` is changed.

Please follow the below code snippets:

1. Create the `embed configuration` object for the report:

```js
const embedConfig = {
        type: "report",
        tokenType: models.TokenType.AAD,
        accessToken: "ACCESS_TOKEN",
        embedUrl: "EMBED_URL",
 };
```

2. Get a reference to the HTML DIV element that contains the embedded report:

```js
const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
```

3. Embed the `Report`:

```js
const report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);
```

4. Add an `event handler` on the `report` object. Inside the event, you can assign the `name` property of the `event` object to the global variable:

```js
report.on('pageChanged', event => {
    const page = event.details.newPage;
    globalVar = page.name;
});
```

Please refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/page-navigation